# What does this word play of ‘Macht’ and ‘macht’ mean?

Tags: german-to-english, wordplay

I came across the following two paragraphs (the first paragraph is included for context purposes) in a *Süddeutsche Zeitung* article “[Alle sollen erben](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/gerechtigkeit-alle-sollen-erben-1.3065948)”:

> Es ist höchste Zeit, dass etwas passiert, denn das Erbe verändert dieses Land, und nicht zum Guten. Trotzdem sprechen die Menschen viel zu selten darüber. Klar, dem Erbe geht der Tod voraus, und Tod ist ein Tabu. Der Politiker schweigt, wer will schon seine Wähler vergrämen. Der Nachbar schweigt, wer will schon zugeben, dass der neue Sportwagen nicht wegen eines großzügigen Jahresbonus in der Garage parkt, sondern weil das Herz des Onkels aussetzte. Und der Millionär, der Papas Villa noch obendrauf bekommt, sagt sowieso nichts - er kennt ja den Neid.
>
> Die Leute hätten solchen Reichtum nicht verdient, ist von links zu
>   hören, man müsse ihnen das Erbe entreißen. **Also: Enteignen, keine
>   Macht für niemand, macht kaputt, was euch kaputt macht!**

What's the meaning of the sentence highlighted in bold in the second paragraph?

Comment: It's a bunch of leftist slogans strung together: dispossess/expropriate (them), no power for nobody (a call for anarchy), destroy what destroys you. _Macht_ (power) and _macht_ (lit. make) is merely a coincidence, not really a pun or play on words.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The meaning of that sentence is:

> Dispossess, no power for nobody, destroy what destroys you.

Since "keine Macht für niemand" and "macht kaputt, was euch kaputt macht" both were prominent slogans of the 68's movement, I don't think this is an intentional word play; it's purely coincidential that both "Macht" (power) and "macht" (make; here as part of the combination "macht kaputt" (destroy; literally: "make broken") occur close to each other.

Comment: Indeed both are songs by Ton Steine Scherben. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keine_Macht_für_Niemand https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macht_kaputt,_was_euch_kaputt_macht